# Bad interaction between alltt package and babel with the italian option

Tags: errors, babel

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{alltt}


\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
    \(\sb{1,1}\)
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
,->\leavevmode \kern \z@ 
                         \char `\,
l.9 \(\sb{1,1
             }\)
```

Changing `\usepackage[italian]{babel}` to `\usepackage[english]{babel}` fixes the issue (but it's not what I need).

I have a suspect that it may be due to babel's shorthands however I have no idea about which shorthands are defined by the `italian` option nor which one might be causing the problem.

Comment: Claudio Beccari recently introduced a “smart comma” feature that, I believe, creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in `babel-italian`. I'm not so happy about the addition of the “intelligent comma” feature. Adding `\NoIntelligentComma` doesn't fix the issue, because it keeps the comma as a math active character and this is the problem in `alltt`.

If you don't need the “intelligent comma”, you can simply add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`,=\virgola}
```

to your preamble (after loading `babel`).

If you want just to solve the issue in `alltt`, then you can add the setting to `alltt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{alltt}

% fix alltt for the comma in math mode
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alltt}{\mathcode`,=\virgola}

\begin{document}

\begin{alltt}
    \(\sb{1,1}\)
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```